# JavaFX Updating UI from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller, javafx

I have a main class

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(View.class);
            View view = new View();
            Platform.runLater(() -> view.changeTitle());
        }
    }
```

and a view JavaFX class

```
    public class View extends Application {

        Stage primaryStage;

        public View() {

        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public void changeTitle() {
           primaryStage.setTitle("YEA!");
       }
    }
```

I want the main class to do something in JavaFX thread but my code doesn't work. In documentation said that I can call Platform.runLater() from any thread I want. If I call Platform.runLater() from JavaFX thread (in start(), for example), everything is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `main(String)` is blocked on `Application.launch(Class)`.

From Oracle Javadocs:

> The launch method does not return until the application has exited, either via a call to Platform.exit or all of the application windows have been closed.

Second, you're creating a new `View` instance on the second line. That will NOT be same instance Application created, so your `Platform.runLater` wouldn't affect the launched application even if that code were reachable before it exited.